# How to combine scale and transform animation in android?

Tags: android, animation

I need to translate and scale image view like on this picture from state 1 to state 2,
State 1 is center of screen, state 2 is any location on screen;
I have combined to animations

```
            a= new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE,startx,Animation.ABSOLUTE,destX*5,Animation.ABSOLUTE,starty,Animation.ABSOLUTE,(destY-32)*5);
            a.setDuration(1000);
            a.setStartOffset(2000);
            as.addAnimation(a);

            a = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0.2f, 1f, 0.2f);
            a.setDuration(1000);
            a.setStartOffset(2000);
            as.addAnimation(a);
```

Where "as" is AnimationSet. When I start the animation.
Everything works well, start and end position ok, but translation between them not going along "straight" line. It goes like an arc, on picture 2;
What kind of scale-animation and translate-animation need I perform and in which order to get straight transformation?

picture 1 [pic1](http://hkar.ru/qOyO)
picture 2 [pic2](http://hkar.ru/qOyP)

Answer (score 0):

After changing order of animations and removing mult by 5 in translateanimation all works ok

```
        a = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0.2f, 1f, 0.2f);
        a.setDuration(1000);
        a.setStartOffset(2000);
        as.addAnimation(a);
        a= new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE,startx,Animation.ABSOLUTE,destX,Animation.ABSOLUTE,starty,Animation.ABSOLUTE,(destY-32));
        a.setDuration(1000);
        a.setStartOffset(2000);
        as.addAnimation(a);
```